# How to remove first word from string in c

Tags: c

I have a string of integer values.  e.g 20 200 2000 21 1

I want to remove the first word (20 in this case).  Any idea how to do this?

I thought about using something like...

```
sscanf(str, "/*somehow put first word here*/ %s", str);
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
char *newStr = str;
while (*newStr != 0 && *(newStr++) != ' ') {}
```

Comment: You can get rid of strlen test by just checking 0 != *newstr.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html), this will set `str` to the substring after the first space, or leave it alone if there is no space;

```
char *tmp = strchr(str, ' ');
if(tmp != NULL)
    str = tmp + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip all characters to the first space, and then skip the space itself, like this:

```
char *orig = "20 200 2000 21 1";
char *res;
// Skip to first space
for (res = orig ; *res && *res != ' ' ; res++)
    ;
// If we found a space, skip it too:
if (*res) res++;
```

This code fragment prints `200 2000 21 1` ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/2HCEGm)).

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest and most elegant way was to do something like that

```
   int garbageInt;
   sscanf(str, "%d %[^\n]\n",&garbageInt,str);
```